# Bag-of-Words (BOW) in VLFeat

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vlfeat

I'm building a project Images Classification with Bag-of-Visual-Words (BoVW) using [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/) library. The BoVW pipeline includes:

1. SIFT
2. k-means
3. Building histogram
4. SVM classification

I can use `vl_sift` and `vl_kmeans` for (1) and (2), but I don't know how to build histogram features and use them in SVM.

Comment: i had vocablulary. But i dont know how to create Histogram. Would you mind helping me to resolve this :(.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given that you already have the "dictionary" from vl_kmeans:

```
[centers] = vl_kmeans(data, numClusters);
```

In order to build histogram of image I, you need to get the 128-D descriptors of that image using vl_sift:

```
[~,D] = vl_sift(I)
```

Each column of D is the descriptor of one interest point (or frame) in image I. Now you need to build the histogram of I based on `D` and the dictionary `centers`. The simplest way is using a for loop:

```
H = zeros(1,numClusters);
for i=1:size(D,2)
  [~, k] = min(vl_alldist(D(:,i), centers)) ;
  H(k) = H(k) + 1;
end
```

Now it is up to you to normalise the histogram H or not, before passing it to SVM. Note that there is possibly a faster way to build the histogram that does not need a loop; but I think my code (in Matlab) is clear enough to explain the algorithm.

Comment: what is meant by this statement, and what is data are these descriptors  [centers] = vl_kmeans(data, numClusters);

Comment: @vicky that statement performs k-means clustering algorithm on **data** where **data** is the feature matrix (each datum per column); and _numClusters_ is number of desired clusters. For more info, please visit [link](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/kmeans.html)